# PHP array findOne

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a *native* possibility in PHP to find all/one elements/keys in array that matches specified condition returned by callback? Like:

```
$default = array_findone($array, function($item) {
    return isset($item['default']) && true === $item['default']
});
```

Instead of:

```
$default = null;
foreach($array as $row) {
    if(isset($row['default']) && true === $row['default']) {
        $default = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **[array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** function:

```
$default = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return isset($item['default']) && true === $item['default']
});
```

Comment: Thank you @xdazz. I didn't remember that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_filter() where first parameter is the array parameter and 2nd parameter is the calback function.

`array_filter($yourArray, function callbackFunc($item){
     return isset($item['default']) && true === $item['default'];
})`

Details are here: [[http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php][1]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php%5d%5b1%5d)